# Sed command fails to replace three lines in another file, no errors displayed

Tags: bash, sed

Here is a minimal version of the .sh file that I am trying to use to change the .cpp file.

```
dir=$PWD
cplusplus_plotter="$dir"/BlueEdge_Plotter_V7.cpp


#Set B
 sed -i \
    -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50]\).*/\1 = "BlueEdge_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat;"/i' \
    -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50]\).*/\1 = "PostiveGrowth_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat;"/i' \
    -e 's!^\([[:blank:]]*log_directory_prefix[30]\).*!\1 = "LOGS_B/LOGS_B;"!i' \
    "$cplusplus_plotter"
#g++ -o SetB_BlueEdge "$cplusplus_plotter"
#./SetB_BlueEdge
```

And here is the part of the `BlueEdge_Plotter_V7.cpp` that I am trying to change

```
    char inputFileName[30] = "input.dat"; //File with the model parameters
    char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50] = "BlueEdge_SetA_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50] = "PostiveGrowth_SetA_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char log_directory_prefix[30] = "LOGS_A/LOGS_A";
    char LINAFileName[30] = "LINA_period_growth.data"; //Normally should be "LINA_period_growth.data"
```

However, even though there is no output in the terminal, the lines stay the same.

**Edit:** here is the desired output.

```
    char inputFileName[30] = "input.dat"; //File with the model parameters
    char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50] = "BlueEdge_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50] = "PostiveGrowth_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char log_directory_prefix[30] = "LOGS_B/LOGS_B";
    char LINAFileName[30] = "LINA_period_growth.data"; //Normally should be "LINA_period_growth.data"
```

I have resolved the issue by escaping the square brackets.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: To match `[` and `]` escape them with a backslash.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595291/sed-e-expression-3-char-59-unknown-option-to-s/595295#595295

Comment: Insert missing `char ` before `log_directory_prefix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to backslash-escape the opening square bracket to match it literally. `a[30]` matches `a3` or `a0` but not literally `a[30]`; for that, you need `a\[30]`. (Backslashing the closing square bracket is optional, but often done for symmetry.)

However, performing in-place substitutions on C++ source files with `sed` seems extremely misdirected. Use the C preprocessor instead, or refactor the code so it reads parameters from a configuration file.